# Convert a list of elements of a specific class to a dictionary with the objects properties as key and values

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a list of objects with each object having one property called "key" and another property called "value".

```
mylist[0].key = "1"
mylist[0].value = "one"
mylist[1].key = "2"
mylist[1].value = "two"
mylist[2].key = "3"
mylist[2].value = "three"
```

How can I convert it into the following dictionary?

```
mydict = {"1": "one", "2": "two", "3": "three"}
```

Answer (score 4):

Using dict comprehension

**Ex:**

```
print({i.key: i.value for i in mylist})
```

Answer (score 3):

Use dictionary comprehension like this -

```
mydict = {obj.key : obj.value for obj in mylist}
```

This considering `mylist` is a list of object